# Euclidean geometry and drawbacks

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, constructive-mathematics

We often in our high school learn the eucledean geometry but while  thinking on this topic i noticed that it was largely confined to 2D shapes but what about geometry with 3D, convex or concave shapes.Is there any other kind of geometry for this purpose or do i have some misunderstanding regarding the topic?I am in 9th grade,so please give an understandable answer!!

Comment: There's three-dimensional Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Well ok..i didnt know.My question seems to be a silly one now

Comment: Good question.  Axiomatic Euclidean Geometry is largely the Geometry of the plane, but there are some interesting $3D$ results in Euclid.  For example, there is the computation of the volume of a pyramid, which is done by invoking a scaling argument which has no precedent in the Elements and which can't be justified by the axioms.  But it is very standard to study Euclidean Geometry only in the plane.

Comment: @user168498 There's no such thing as a silly question. (Well, except when one asks a question because he/she is too lazy to try to answer it by him/herself, but this is of course not the case here.)

Comment: It can be argued that Euclid's ultimate goal in his *Elements* is to construct the Platonic solids, which seems to be exactly where you want to go.  I think that the only reason we stick with plane geometry at the secondary level is time.  It is also perhaps worth noting that Euclidean geometry can be generalized to $n$-dimensional spaces, though such spaces are pretty hard to visualize. ;)

Comment: Thx daniel robert nicoud